# WPF handle column header click

Tags: wpf, datagrid

how to handle a column header click (WPF's DataGrid)
I want to get clicked column header's text from code and change it's background...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ButtonBase.Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx) can be used